# Ionic 3 I cannot return value from Diagnostic plugin using a provider

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am using a provider to get user's location and using the geolocation and diagnostic plugins for that purpose.

I am having trouble returning a value from the function and using it in my page where I import the provider.

In the provider, here is my function:

```
isDeviceEnabled(): boolean {
this.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled().then(result => {
return result;
}).catch(e => {console.error(e); return false;});}
```

isLocationEnabled() of this plugin returns a boolean, either true or false. I would like to use it in the .ts file of my page as such:

```
export class MainPage {
public deviceEnabled: boolean;
constructor(){}
....
ionViewWillEnter() {
this.deviceEnabled = this.getLoc.isDeviceEnabled();
}
....
}
```

So that I display it in HTML as such:

```
{{deviceEnabled}}
```

In the provider file, the error messages I get is:

```
A function whose declared type neither void or any 
must return a value.
```

When I change the type of function to any, the variable doesn't show up in my html because it is undefined.

There is a time lag because the diagnostic function takes time to process. Probably by the time the function returns a value the page gets an undefined value.

Is this a simple mistake I am making or do I have to resort to using events to pass values from a provider? Because you may subscribe to events.

If the function could return a value I could use it as such:

```
//*in provider
passValue():string { return 'this is the value' }

//*in page ts
public val: string;
...
this.val = this.provider.passValue();

//*in HTML
{{ val }}
```

But because the function does not return a value in the traditional sense (because it evaluates a promise using then()), I cannot do this.

By the way I was able to achieve this by using this in the provider:

```
isDeviceEnabled() {
this.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled().then(result => 
{
this.events.publish('device-check', result); //*publish event
}).catch(e => {console.error(e)}); 
}
```

And this subscriber in ts file of page. First call function to get status,
then subscribe to the result.

```
this.getLoc.isDeviceEnabled(); 
this.events.subscribe('device-check', (enabled) => { 
//....
)}
```

However, I am still wondering if there is a different way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I was able to achieve this by using events.

Answer (score 1):

isDeviceEnabled returns promise. So you need to access in the component using .then.

```
isDeviceEnabled(): boolean {
   return this.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled().then(result => {
      return result;
   }).catch(e => {console.error(e); return false;});
}

export class MainPage {
  public deviceEnabled: boolean;
  constructor(){}
   ....
   ionViewWillEnter() {
        this.getLoc.isDeviceEnabled().then(status=>{
           this.deviceEnabled = status;
        });
   }
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks... the function in provider still gives the same error message: "A function that is boolean should return a value"... unless you have a statement at the end that returns something as such:  `isDeviceEnabled(): boolean {
   this.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled().then(result => {
      return result;
   }).catch(e => {console.error(e); return false;});
   return false;}` But when you do this, the function returns false before it gets to processing the plugin's isLocationEnabled() function...

Comment: For the second function in the .ts file, there is also another error message: "Property then does not  exist on type boolean"

Comment: missed to add return statement. please check now.